# Gravity Form Repeater File/Media Upload Not Working

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

Gravity form repeater currently not support file/media upload as mentioned in [doc](https://docs.gravityforms.com/repeater-fields/#h-limitations). I am wondering is there anyone who fixed that issue or any solution that can help me?

I am getting following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin allows file uploads within a repeater field:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/

(see this question) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63651671/1844720